# Check LatLng inside Polygon without using google map

Tags: algorithm

I have many polygon with LatLng and one point

how check point inside polygon without using google map?

tanks for help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find coordinates inside a rectangular area constructed by lat/long GPS pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627211/find-coordinates-inside-a-rectangular-area-constructed-by-lat-long-gps-pairs)

Comment: you have tagged this question with three different programming languages, and shown no effort to solve the issue yourself. Please flesh-out (expand upon) your issue in order for people to provide a good answer.